# Extending biholomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ is a bounded domain having no isolated boundary points. Let $M \subset D$ be a subset having no limit point in $D$. I want to prove that a biholomorphic function $f\colon D\setminus M \to D\setminus M$ can be extended to a biholomorphic function $D\to D$.

Choose a point $z_0 \in M$. Using that $M$ has no limit point in $D$ and that $D$ is bounded, it is not hard to see that $f$ extends to a holomorphic
$$
\tilde{f} \colon D\setminus M \cup \{z_0\} \to \mathbb{C}.
$$
In fact, $\tilde{f}(z_0)\in \overline{D\setminus M} \subset \overline{D}$. I am having trouble proving that $\tilde{f}(z_0)$ is actually in $D$, i.e. not in the boundary of $D$. The assumption that $D$ has no isolated boundary points has not been used yet. However, $\tilde{f}(z_0)$ is not isolated anyway because it is the limit of a sequence $f(z_n)$ with $z_n \in D\setminus M$.

I appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Use the open mapping theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for your comment. This tells me that there is some $r$  such that the open disk $B_r(\tilde{f}(z_0))$ is contained in $D\setminus M \cup \{ \tilde{f}(z_0)\}$, i.e. the punctured disk $B^\ast_r(\tilde{f}(z_0))$ is contained in $D\setminus M$. $\tilde{f}(z_0)$ being an element of the boundary of $D$ means that for each $p$, $B^\ast_p(\tilde{f}(z_0)) \cap D \neq \varnothing$. I still don't see how that helps.

Comment: Look at $B_{\rho}^{\ast}(\tilde{f}(z_0)) \cap \partial D$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I had a wrong understanding of the phrase "no isolated boundary points". What it should actually mean is that $\partial D \subset \mathbb{C}$ has no isolated points. With this in mind, I am able to solve this.